# Copy code from AWS Glue Visual ETL and create new ETL script. Getting Connection timed out, The Network Adapter could not establish the connection"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have a AWS glue ETL that load data from Oracle to S3. I copied the exact same code from AWS Glue Visual ETL and created new ETL script. The AWS Glue ETL is working fine in Visual editor but the ETL Script got error. I am using a Connection that connects to an Oracle Database.

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
OracleSQL_node1700470932771 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    connection_type="oracle",
    connection_options={
        "useConnectionProperties": "true",
        "dbtable": "TEMP_CUST_METRICS_CHURN_2023_TAM",
        "connectionName": "dec_data_test",
    },
    transformation_ctx="OracleSQL_node1700470932771",
)
# Script generated for node Amazon S3
AmazonS3_node1700470954587 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame=OracleSQL_node1700470932771,
    connection_type="s3",
    format="glueparquet",
    connection_options={
        "path": "s3://dsc-dm-data/dec_data/TEMP_CUST_METRICS_CHURN_2023_TAM/",
        "partitionKeys": [],
    },
    format_options={"compression": "snappy"},
    transformation_ctx="AmazonS3_node1700470954587",
)
job.commit()
```

And I got the below error when creating a DataFrame from Oracle.

```
IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection.
java.io.IOException: Connection timed out
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
```

Any other thoughts or solutions are appreciated! Many thanks